# Need help regarding code c#

Tags: c#

I have class in c#

```
public class CompositeResource : Control
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
    public ResourceCollection Resources { get { return _resources; } }
}

public class Resource
{
    [Bindable(true), DefaultValue(""), Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.UrlEditor, System.Design, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor)), Description("Specifies the URL of a resource to reference in the CompositeControl. The URL may be relative, root relative or absolute."), UrlProperty]
    public String Url { get; set; }

    [Bindable(true), DefaultValue(""), Description("Specifies the name of a resource to be used as a reference in the CompositeControl. The ReferenceName is typically used in conjunction with the Sprite control.")]
    public String ReferenceName { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceCollection : List<Resource> 
{ 
}
```

I just need to add multiple resource like

```
CompositeResource cr = new CompositeResource();
cr.Type = Xpedite.Resources.ResourceType.Css;
cr.ReferenceName = "hello";
cr.Resources.Add({new Resource().Url="\style\p1.css",new Resource().Url="\style\p2.css" });
```

but the last line giving me the error when I want add multiple resources and each resource instance has property like url.
I think i am wrong but not being able to capture where is there problem.

Comment: Add the error message. And maybe strip down your example code a bit to clearify.

Comment: If you have an error always paste the details. If its a runtime error this should include what exception is being thrown mainly, a stack trace if you think it would be useful and of course where the exception is being thrown. If its a compile error then the compiler message and the line associated with it. People might be able to tell from just the code but there is no need to make it harder than it needs to be. :)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: D'oh! Didn't notice that. I shall go delete that embarrassing comment forthwith, leaving just these two ghostly comments to confuse future readers. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong

```
cr.Resources.Add({new Resource().Url="\style\p1.css",new Resource().Url="\style\p2.css" });
```

should be

```
cr.Resources.Add(new Resource() { Url = @"\style\p1.css" });
cr.Resources.Add(new Resource() { Url = @"\style\p2.css" });
```

Comment: your first syntax does not work rather gives error. second work fine.

Comment: The first one was **your own**, I just quoted it for clarification.

Answer (score 7):

I think your code should look like this:

```
cr.Resources.Add(new Resource(){ Url= @"\style\p1.css" });
cr.Resources.Add(new Resource(){ Url= @"\style\p2.css" });
```

Your current code is no valid C# code.